# How to create shortcuts to call forms from an existing form in oracle forms 12c

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to create user defined shortcut keys (e.g shift A) to call another form in my oracle weblogic application. The shortcut keys are user defined and stored in a table through another form.

The main menu itself is a form actually.

Basically im just asking how to call a form from an already open form when the user presses a certain key.

Is it necessary to create a custom javascript trigger?

What does the KEY-OTHERS trigger do?

[image]

edit : well Alt by default opens this menu so I cant use Alt

Answer (score 0):

What you described, sounds like an **access key** - if this "main menu" form uses **buttons** to navigate to other forms.

If that's so, then

- open button's Property Palette (left part of the screenshot)
- go to its "Access Key" property
- put a letter in there

  - for example, in a screenshot I posted, letter "A" is a "natural" choice as that button's label begins with that letter
- when you run the form (middle part of the screenshot), access key is **underlined**
- for more info, press the `F1` keyboard key while in Property Palette's "Access Key" property

[image]

Also, you might be interested in reading about [keyboard shortcuts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/web.1111/e28163/ap_kbd.htm).

Comment: No my app has tree nodes, no button in main menu. Well i could make invisible buttons and assign them shortcuts but the form would open whenever the user pressed A. I want Shift A or Ctrl A

Comment: Read what's been said. It is **Alt**-A, not just A.

Comment: Aha, it's a hierarchical tree, after all. Well, what I explained won't work there, and I don't know how to do it without (a lot?) of programming, sorry.